# How to convert datetime from PowerShell output to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

While trying to write a lastLogon date to DB from PS I am getting the output `10-10-2021 21:14:40` but when writing this to my DB (MS SQL) the date converts `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` instead of `2021-10-10 21:14:40.000` and any attempts to convert the output using e.g. `$DateStr = $lastLogon.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss")` has failed so far

**My PS Script:**

```
.....
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$EmploymentUser = Invoke-SQL -sqlCommand "select * from EmploymentUser where LastFlowEditDate Is Not NUll AND (EndDate Is Null OR EndDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND StartDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY Initials;"

foreach($User in $EFP_EmploymentUser)
{
Get-ADUser $User.Initials -Properties lastLogon | Select @{Name="lastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}}

    Invoke-SQL -sqlCommand "UPDATE EFP_EmploymentUser SET lastLogonAD  = '$($lastLogon)' WHERE ID like $($User.ID)"

}
```

Any one who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a date-time string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format - e.g. `2021-10-10T21:14:40` - which you can obtain with the [standard `s` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier):

```sh
foreach ($user in $EFP_EmploymentUser) {

  $lastlogon = [datetime]::FromFileTime(
    (Get-ADUser $User.Initials -Properties lastLogon).lastlogon
  )

  Invoke-SQL -sqlCommand "
      UPDATE EFP_EmploymentUser
      SET lastLogonAD  = '$($lastLogon.ToString('s'))'
      WHERE ID like $($user.ID)
    "

}
```

The advantage of using a ISO 8601-format string is that it is by definition *culture-invariant*.

A simplified example, using [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date):

```
PS> (Get-Date).ToString('s')
2021-10-10T17:42:41
```

Note: If `Get-Date` happens to be involved anyway, you can more simply use its `-Format` parameter:

```
PS> Get-Date -Format s
2021-10-10T17:42:41
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The primary problem with your code was that you tried to use an undefined variable, `$lastlogon`, instead of accessing the `.lastlogon` *property* on the current pipeline input object, `$_`, as created by your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call.

In the context of string interpolation (inside a `"..."` string), the undefined `$lastlogon` variable expanded to the *empty string*, which is why the SQL command ended up assigning the earliest date-time value it supports, `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Additionally, your `Get-ADUser ...` statement was not connected to the `Invoke-SQL` call, so that the former's output - a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a [calculated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) `.lastlogon` property created via [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) -  was simply passed through.

Comment: The updated code works like a charm @mklement0 ;-) .. Thank you so much for your help, I really appriciate it :-)